# Invariance of spectrum under conjugation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, sp.spectral-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint invertible operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with a continuous spectrum, means the spectral measure is nonatomic. For which class of invertible operators $V$( with continuous spectrum) other than unitary $VTV^{*}$ also have continuous spectrum?

Comment: Obviously it works for nonzero scalar multiples of unitaries.

Comment: I dont want that @Israel!! Something nontrivial I am expecting

Comment: "Something nontrivial I am expecting" -- you should not expect other people to do the work of formulating a well-defined question for you.

Comment: @Yemon I formulated the correct question, somebody answered it in the wrong way, I made him understand the mistake!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, the only such operators $V$ that work for all $T$ are scalar multiples of the identity.

Suppose $V$ is not a scalar multiple of a unitary.  Then there are linearly independent vectors $v$, $w$ such that $V^* V v = w$.
Let $T$ be a self-adjoint invertible operator such that $Tw = v$.  Then $VTV^* (Vv) = V T w = V v$, so $V T V^*$ does not have continuous spectrum.
All that remains is to show that such $T$ can be chosen with continuous spectrum, which is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum of an operator $T$ is invariant under conjugation by invertible operators $V$, i.e. $$\sigma(T)=\sigma(VTV^{-1}).$$ So, if your operator has continuous spectrum also its conjugate $VTV^{-1}$ does, because the spectral measures are the same.

Comment: yes I know $\sigma(T)=\sigma(VTV^{-1})$, but my question about $VTV^{*}$ not $VTV^{-1}$

Comment: Ok, so perhaps you may want to slightly rephrase your question so that it is clearer.